# What is DOMDocument doing to my string?

Tags: php, unicode, domdocument

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$str = '<p>Hello®</p>';

var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str)); 

$dom->loadHTML($str);

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

[View](http://codepad.viper-7.com/94BLvA).

#### Outputs

```
string(5) "UTF-8"

string(158) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Hello&Acirc;&reg;</p></body></html>
"
```

Why did my Unicode `®` get converted to `&Acirc;&reg;` and how do I stop this?

<sup>Am I going crazy today?</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text editor says `"®"` in UTF-8, but the bytes in the file say `"Â®"` in Latin-1 (or a similar encoding), which is what PHP is using to read it. Using the character entity reference will remove this ambiguity.

```
>>> print u'®'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
Â®
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me (+1), but what should my next step be? I feel like a beginner all over again :P

Comment: *My* next step would be to write it as `&reg;` in the code; it's not worth fighting PHP over stuff like this, since there isn't a great chance of actually *winning* the fight everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an xml encoding tag (and take it out later). This works for me on things that are not stock Centos 5.x (ubuntu, cpanel's php):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$str = '<p>Hello®</p>';
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($str)); 
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8">'.$str);
var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

This is what you get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<?xml encoding="utf-8"><html><body><p>Hello&reg;</p></body></html>
```

Except on days when you get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<?xml encoding="utf-8"><html><body><p>Hello&Acirc;&reg;</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this decoding the UTF-8 before passing it to loadHTML.

```
$dom->loadHTML( utf8_decode( $html ) );
```

`saveHTML()` seems to decode special chars like German umlauts to their HTML entities. (Although I set `$dom->substituteEntities=false;`... o.O)

This is quite strange, though, as the documentation states:

> The DOM extension uses UTF-8 encoding.

(http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php, search for utf8)

Oh dear, encoding in PHP poses problems again and again... never ending story.