# PHP DOMXPath loop through search and find child div value

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I am loading external HTML content into a variable like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://localhost');
```

The page has a set of loops of `<ul>` like this:

```
<ul class="items-list">
<li>Title1</li>
<li>Description1</li>
<li>Location1</li>
</ul>
<!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
<a href="#">
<div class="item-price">£10</div>
<a/>

<ul class="items-list">
<li>Title2</li>
<li>Description2</li>
<li>Location2</li>
</ul>
<!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
<a href="#">
<div class="item-price">£15</div>
</a>

<ul class="items-list">
<li>Title3</li>
<li>Description3</li>
<li>Location3</li>
</ul>
<!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
<a href="#">
<div class="item-price">£20</div>
</a>

<ul class="items-list">
<li>Title4</li>
<li>Description4</li>
<li>Location4</li>
</ul>
<!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
<a href="#">
<div class="item-price">£25</div>
</a>
```

I have the following code that uses DOMXPath to search for all the items-list UL's and then I can loop through it and echo it.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$items = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='items-list']"); 

foreach ($items as $node) { 
  echo $node->textContent;
}
```

This work's perfectly. However, I need help displaying the price of each one of these loops which comes from the div class called item-price which is after the UL but not immediately after.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($items as $node) { 
  echo $node->textContent;
  $div = $xpath->query('.//following::div[@class="item-price"][1]', $node); 
  echo $div[0]->nodeValue ."\n\n";
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/930420)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work howevever, the price seems to be coming with extra symbol like this: Â£25

Comment: @Ahmed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062785/what-is-domdocument-doing-to-my-string

Comment: Just write `$dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following-sibling axis

```
$xpath->query("//ul[@class='items-list']/following-sibling::div[@class='item-price']");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. returns completely empty with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Using the original query combined with a `following-sibling` operator perhaps will suffice.

```
define('BR','<br />');

$strhtml='<ul class="items-list">
    <li>Title1</li>
    <li>Description1</li>
    <li>Location1</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
    <div class="item-price">£10</div>

    <ul class="items-list">
    <li>Title2</li>
    <li>Description2</li>
    <li>Location2</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
    <div class="item-price">£15</div>

    <ul class="items-list">
    <li>Title3</li>
    <li>Description3</li>
    <li>Location3</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
    <div class="item-price">£20</div>

    <ul class="items-list">
    <li>Title4</li>
    <li>Description4</li>
    <li>Location4</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE BETWEEN THE UL AND THE PRICE DIV -->
    <div class="item-price">£25</div>';


    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom ); 
    $items = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='items-list'] | //ul[@class='items-list']/following-sibling::div[@class='item-price']"); 
    if( $items && $items->length > 0 ){
        foreach ( $items as $node ) { 
            echo $node->textContent . BR;
        }
    }
```

The above outputs

```
Title1 Description1 Location1 
Â£10
Title2 Description2 Location2 
Â£15
Title3 Description3 Location3 
Â£20
Title4 Description4 Location4 
Â£25
```

---

Given the change to the html content a minor modification to the XPath query is required as the div containing the prices is no longer a direct sibling - though it could be.

```
$items = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='items-list'] | //ul[@class='items-list']/following::div[@class='item-price']");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, is it supposed to be in the same $node->textContent ?I tried print_r($node->textContent); [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)

Comment: ah - remove `BR` ~ that is a constant `define('BR','<br />');` - might be the reason

Comment: Thanks RamRaider, but it appears that the <div class="item-price">£10</div> is inside a <a href> so it actually looks like this <a href=""><div class="item-price">£10</div></a> And because of this a href it does'nt work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: if I remove the a tags then it works, but with the A tags it doesnt work. I need it to work with the A tags. any ideas?

Comment: can you update your question to reflect the actual data